# Need to extract value from TEXT column

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have table `xx_debug` which two column `ID` and `TEXT` column.

We are storing `ID`, `TEXT` as below

```
10, "POST_OPERATION_API: INV_ITEM_STATUS_CP.CREATE_ITEM_ERES_EVENT(p_commit => 'T',p_init_msg_list => 'T',p_event_name  => 'oracle.apps.inv.itemCreate',p_event_key   => '148-850154',p_caller_type => 'CREATE_ITEM_POST_APPROVAL',p_org_id      => 148,p_inventory_item_id => 850154);"
```

Now, for TEXT column record, I need to fetch `p_org_id => 148` and `p_inventory_item_id => 850154` out of entire text.

How I can get `p_org_id => 148` and `p_inventory_item_id => 850154` into some variable for each `p_org_id` and  `p_inventory_item_id`?

I tried using `extract` and `regexp_substr` but not getting the exact result in pl/sql.

Answer (score 0):

Use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` and look for the prefix and then the digits and return the capturing group containing the digits:

```sql
SELECT id,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(text, 'p_org_id\s*=>\s*(\d+)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS org_id,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(text, 'p_inventory_item_id\s*=>\s*(\d+)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS inventory_id 
FROM   xx_debug
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE xx_debug (id, text) AS
SELECT 10, q'{POST_OPERATION_API: INV_ITEM_STATUS_CP.CREATE_ITEM_ERES_EVENT(p_commit => 'T',p_init_msg_list => 'T',p_event_name  => 'oracle.apps.inv.itemCreate',p_event_key   => '148-850154',p_caller_type => 'CREATE_ITEM_POST_APPROVAL',p_org_id      => 148,p_inventory_item_id => 850154);}' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID | ORG_ID | INVENTORY_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 148 | 850154 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/wBaqn7Tw)